# Component does not change state when going from dynamic route to static

Tags: reactjs

I have a route `/users` that prints a list of users, each user is a link to a dynamic route `/users/:cn` that displays the user details.
Navigating from `/users` to `/users/:cn` is possible but from `/users/:cn` to `/users` is not, the url changes but nothing happens, and in the backend log there is no get request to the`/users` page . But if i am on  `/users/:cn` and navigate to `/otherRoute` it works fine, or if i am on `/users` and navigate to `/otherRoute` also work fine. I think i need to update the state somehow when i am on the dynamic route. Any help?

I already tried wrapping the component `userWrapper` with `withRouter` but that does not work.

users.js

```
import React ,{Component} from "react"
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Switch, Route, withRouter} from "react-router-dom"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import User from "../components/users"
import MainComponentWrapper from "../components/mainComponentWrapper"
import UserDetails from "../components/userDetails"


const userDetailsWrapper = props => {
  const url = "http://localhost:5000/user/" + props.match.params.cn
  return (
    <MainComponentWrapper url={url}>
      <UserDetails />
    </MainComponentWrapper>
  )
}

const userWrapper = props => {

  const url = "http://localhost:5000/user"
  return (
    <MainComponentWrapper url={url}>
      <User />
    </MainComponentWrapper>
  )
}


const IndexPage = () => (
      <div>
    <Router >
       <Layout>
         <Switch>

               <Route exact path="/users" component={(userWrapper)}/>
               <Route exact path="/users/:cn"  component={userDetailsWrapper} />

           </Switch>
        </Layout>
    </Router>
 </div>

)


export default IndexPage
```

layout.jsx

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import React from "react"
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer"
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline"
import List from "@material-ui/core/List"
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider"
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem"
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon"
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText"
import ExitToApp from "@material-ui/icons/ExitToApp"
import PeopleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/People"
import ListIcon from "@material-ui/icons/List"
import ComputerIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Computer"
import { navigate } from "gatsby"



const drawerWidth = 240

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
}))

function Layout({ children }) {

  const classes = useStyles()



  const handleLogout = event => {
    localStorage.removeItem("access_token")
    window.location.replace("/")
  }
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="permanent"
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper,
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <List>
          <ListItem button onClick={() => navigate("/users")}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <PeopleIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={"Users"} />
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem button onClick={() => navigate("/machines")}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <ComputerIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={"Machines"} />
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem button onClick={() => navigate("/audits")}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <ListIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={"Audit"} />
          </ListItem>
        </List>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          <ListItem button onClick={handleLogout}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <ExitToApp />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={"Logout"} />
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        {children}
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

Layout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}

export default Layout
```

MainComponentWrapper.jsx

```
import React from "react"
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import CircularProgress from "@material-ui/core/CircularProgress"

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
  },
  progress: {
    margin: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}))

export default function MainComponentWrapper({ url, children }) {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [data, setData] = React.useState()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + window.localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
      },
    })
      .then(resp => {
        return resp.json()
      })
      .then(fetchedData => {
        setData(fetchedData)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
         window.localStorage.removeItem("access_token")
         window.location.replace("/")
      })
  }, [url])
  if (data === undefined) {
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CircularProgress className={classes.progress} />
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {React.cloneElement(children, { data: data })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: is that because your urls are `"http://localhost:5000/user"` instead of `"http://localhost:5000/users"` ? if that isn't the issue, can you make a demoable version in a codesandbox or something because your setup looks fine

Comment: why `component={(userWrapper)}` instead of `component={userWrapper}`? I'm sure thats not the issue but seems strange, I assume you're using the navlink component from react-router? as mentioned by Tom above are you routing to `/user` or `/users` add some console.logs to above the returns and see if either of the components re-render when you're clicking the link. You also should be able to use relative links instead of the full localhost path

Comment: On my backend are routes that fetch data with that url.The main MainComponentWrapper does that job i just need to pass the url so he fetches the data.

Comment: @Ross Johnson component={(userWrapper)} the () stayed because i was using withRouter there and forgot to remove them, they do no harm, i am using navigate from gatsby, and routing to /users, if you check my routes you can see that. The url that i pass in the wrappers is to fetch data from the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **@reach/router** instead of **react-router-dom** solved the issue for the author. Gatsby library that was used to *navigate* the pages is built over **@reach/router** thus using **react-router-dom** caused conflicts. Code changes for *@react/router*

```
import { Router } from "@reach/router"

...

<Router>
    <UserWrapper path="/users" />
    <UserDetailsWrapper path="/users/:cn" />
</Router>
```

*Read comments* for details. Answer by author can be found below.

**Discarded**

All seems well could you please also share the code for your `<MainComponentWrapper url={url}>`. How are you calling the API there specifically in which *lifecycle method*?

Comment: All seems well but for the sake of debugging try removing the [url] from useEffect() see if that makes the GET request.

Comment: that will not make the get request, that url is my backend route that returns data.I think that i need to pass state to the user.js page so he knows the state changed when moving between /users and /users/:cn, how can i do that?

Comment: I have tried mimicking the cod e works fine for me except I had to use "gatsby-link" only using "gatsby" was giving me build time errors...

Comment: Also since otherRoutes are working have you tried changing the name for /users?

Comment: all routes are working fine except going from /users/:cn to /users, i can navigate everywhere except from this specific path. how did you use gatsby link? because when i use it did not work for me, i had to use the react link

Comment: I was referring to the `import { navigate } from "gatsby-link"` the "gatsby" didn't work for me. Simply from `npm i gatsby`

Comment: Hey @PatrickJosé  see if this resolves your issue [Recommendations for programmatic, in-app navigation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#recommendations-for-programmatic-in-app-navigation) Basically it says you cannot use `<Link>` or `navigate` from gatsby with query parameters though it specifies _# and ?_ parameters.

Comment: The other problem may have to do with the **preloading behaviour** through gatsby `<Link>` This is what their documentation says: _Gatsby’s <Link> component enables linking to internal pages as well as a powerful performance feature called preloading._

Comment: And since gatsby extends `@reach/router` using `react-router-dom` might be causing some conflicts for that simply replace your users.js as follow: _remove_ the `<switch>` and replace `<Route />` with `<userWrapper path="/users" />` and `<userDetailsWrapper path="/users/:cn"  />` [@reach/route example](https://reach.tech/router/example/url-params)

Answer (score 0):

So i fixed the problem, @m.sohail  was right.
I had conflicts using `react-router-dom`, I need to use `@reach/router`, and made some code changes.

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import User from "../components/users"
import MainComponentWrapper from "../components/mainComponentWrapper"
import UserDetails from "../components/userDetails"
import { Router } from "@reach/router"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <div>
    <Layout>
      <Router>
        <UserWrapper path="/users" />
        <UserDetailsWrapper path="/users/:cn" />
      </Router>
    </Layout>
  </div>
)
```